# How to get an Input() with directory completion and command line recall?

Tags: command-line, autocompletion

So I have an input, something like this:

```
let dir = input("What is the directory you're looking for? ", "", "dir")
```

This works great for typing and and getting directory input. But what if the path was really long and I want to run the command again? Normally I would just press  <kbd>↑</kbd>  for command line recall, however when I do this it simply tries to complete a directory which is not what I want. I want <kbd>Tab</kbd> to complete directories, and  <kbd>↑</kbd>  to do command line recall. Is there any way to get this behavior without defining a custom completion function?

Comment: Ctrl+x , Ctrl+f completes filenames as well as directories. So, you can map them to tab in normal mode.

Comment: @SibiCoder: yes but not in this case. CTRL-F open the command line window if executed from the command line `:h c_CTRL-F`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply want to recall the last text given as an argument to `input()`, you could try the following mapping:

```
cnoremap <expr> <Up> getcmdtype() ==# '@' ? '<C-E><C-U>' . histget('@') : '<Up>'
```

Which can be broken down like this:

- `<expr>`: type the evaluation of an expression
- `getcmdtype() ==# '@'`: check whether you are on the input line
- `'<C-E><C-U>' . histget('@')`: if the previous test succeeded, hit `<C-E><C-U>` to clear the input line, then type the last entry from the input history (`histget('@')`)
- `'<Up>'`: otherwise, if you are somewhere else (command-line, expression register, search ...), simply hit `<Up>`

---

If you want to navigate across all the entries of the input history, you could try the following code:

```
let s:input_hist_index=0

function! s:InputHistory(dir) abort
    let s:input_hist_index += a:dir
    return "\<C-E>\<C-U>" . histget('@', s:input_hist_index)
endfunction

cnoremap <expr> <Up> getcmdtype() ==# '@' ? <SID>InputHistory(-1) : '<Up>'
cnoremap <expr> <Down> getcmdtype() ==# '@' ? <SID>InputHistory(1) : '<Down>'
```

It's similar to the previous mapping, except it must track where you are in the input history, hence the script-local variable `s:input_hist_index`. There may be another way of doing it, maybe a native function, but I didn't find one in `:h history-functions`.

---

You can get more information with the following help topics:

```
:h <expr>
:h getcmdtype()
:h histget()
:h c_ctrl-e
:h c_ctrl-u
```

Comment: Cool. Yeah, I think this will work. Thanks! Ok, I understand all of this except one thing: Could you tell me what `<C-U>` does in this context? I assume it's not the scrolling function that I find in `:help CTRL-U`.

Comment: @Tumbler41 `<C-U>` deletes from the cursor up to the beginning of the line. Without it, whenever you would hit `<Up>`, the mapping would add a new entry from the input history on the command-line without clearing it first. So `<C-U>` makes sure the command-line is always cleared before inserting something. You can get this information here: `:h c_ctrl-u`